# SQL Server stored procedure timeout when called through .Net application

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance

I am using Windows Form application (.NET Framework 4) that connect to SQL Server to run a stored procedure .

When I run the stored procedure in SSMS directly, it is OK, but when I run it through the application, after a long time hang, it times out.

Of course when I reset SQL Server, application runs the stored procedure just fine, for about 40 days and after this time it starts to timeout again.

I clean buffer of SQL Server and increased timeout property of connection, but it didn't solve my problem.

How could I release resource of SQL Server to solve this problem.

Comment: Probably you are using SqlCommand in order to execute SP. Specify TimeOut parameter to be zero ( 0 ). See more on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: could you put the code of .NET and your SP?

Comment: Thanks for guides,I could increase Timeout Parameter  as you wrote , but my problem is that the query run  very good when i reset SQL  , but after about 40 days again TimeOut starts .  it seems resource of SQL is Consumed gradually , i think  if i could release resource of sql (not by reset) the problem resolved  .